# Time returned as DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, oledb, sybase

I have a problem with the return data type Time in a Sybase database.

I am communicating with the database through an OLE DB connection from a .NET WCF (ASEOLEDB for Sybase 15.7) and I have a column as Time datatype that should return schedules as follows:

```
Lector = Comando.ExecuteReader();
    if (Lector != null && Lector.HasRows)
        while (Lector.Read())
            listadoSalida.Add(new ComboBoxDisplay { Description = Lector[3] + " - " + Lector[4], Value = Lector[1].ToString() });
```

When I run locally on the database, the return is correct and returns schedules as follows:

```
09:00:00 - 10:00:00
10:00:00 - 11:00:00
...
```

But when I publish the wcf on the server, return schedules is incorrect and is shown as follows:

```
1/1/1900 9:00:00  AM - 1/1/1900 10:00:00 AM
1/1/1900 10:00:00 AM - 1/1/1900 11:00:00 AM
```

Has anyone had a similar problem?
How you solved it?

Thank you in advance for your help

**EDIT: The data type of the column that I need to return, not TIMESPAN but TIME, then, the strange thing is that when returning from the WCF, the data returns me the date next to the time**

Comment: What does your service and data contracts look like?

Comment: You can't have a `TimeSpan` like `1/1/1900 10:00:00 AM`. This is a `DateTime`. Your `Lector[3]` variable is `1/1/1900 9:00:00  AM` and `Lector[4]` is  `1/1/1900 10:00:00 AM`? What are the types of these columns?

Comment: You need to find where it returns the date and combine that with the time to create a correct DateTime.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a TimeSpan of 09:00:00 for this? That's a _time_ , not a TimeSpan.

Comment: I edited the question, because the column is of type TIME and not of TIMESPAN type.

I need to return schedules in the following format "HH: mm: ss - HH: mm: ss" and locally works fine but posted returns with date and "AM"

Comment: So why don't you have the code displaying it use the format string `HH: mm: ss`? This is a display problem on your far end not a type problem on your db side. The reason it "looks correct" on your local side is that code is already "hiding" the date portion, it is still there. Show the code showing how you are looking at these values from the "WCF side"

Comment: wcf communicates with the database through a stored procedure, and the execution of this, is in the wording of the question